# How to translate a UML class diagram into code (java)?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, uml, diagrams

I am a beginner (this will soon become obvious) and I can not figure out how to translate this diagram:
[UML class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/em8C8.jpg)

What I need help with is how to create the association and dependency relationships. For example, could you tell me what the completed lab4.SimpleDraw would look like, according to this diagram? From that, I should be able to figure out the rest on my own. So far, all I have for this one specifically is:

```
package lab4;

public class SimpleDraw {

}
```

so basically nothing.

Answer (score 1):

- First row: Class name
- Second row: Fields of the class
- Third row: methods of the class

If it's underline this mean the method/field is static.

Before any of it you see a "-" or "+"

- If it's a `-` this mean it's private. (In this case i think the circle is red)
- If it's a `+` this mean it's public. (In this case the circle is green)
- If nothing in Java could mean package visibility

To learn more about dependency read [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsdvhelp/v6r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cdepend.html)

About dependency extends class read [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsahelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.viz.j2se.doc/topics/cgeneralizn.html).

But i don't see any of this, the lines here say it will use your classes in methods/fields.